# Using OpenLayers with RequireJS and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, openlayers, require

I'm trying to get an app running that uses both AngularJS and RequireJS. I'm having problems getting my OpenLayers lib to work in this setup.

I set the main AMD-modules in the main.js:

```
require.config(
    {
        baseUrl: 'scripts',
        paths: {
            // Vendor modules
            angular: 'vendor/angular/angular',
            openLayers: 'vendor/openlayers-debug',
            other modules.....
        },
        shim: {
            angular: {
                exports: 'angular'
            },
            openLayers: {
                exports: 'OpenLayers'
            },
            other modules....
        }
    }
);

require(['openLayers',
        'angular',
        'app',
        'controllers/olMapController',
        'directives/olMap',
        other modules...
    ], function(OpenLayers) {
        return OpenLayers;
    }
);
```

Then in the angular controller I use for the initialisation of OpenLayers, I try to indicate that openlayers-debug.js is a dependency:

```
define(['openLayers'],
    function(OpenLayers) {
        controllers.controller('olMapController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
            console.log('Loaded olMapController. OpenLayers version: ' + OpenLayers.VERSION_NUMBER);
        }]);
    }
);
```

Well, this doesn't work. SOMETIMES the olMapController function is executed, but mostly not. The console then just displays an error stating:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'olMapController' is not a function, got undefined

So, I think OpenLayers hasn't finished loading yet, but somehow require thinks it has and continues loading code that depends on OpenLayers, in this case the olMapController. It then can't find its dependency, whereupon Angular returns this error message. Or something like that...? Sometimes something happens that makes OpenLayers load fast enought for it to be present when it is loaded as a dependency. What that is, I can't tell.

I left out other libraries and modules require and define to keep the code readable. I hope the example is still understandable.

Any ideas on what I could do to get openlayers to load well? The error message disappears when I leave the `['openLayers']` dependency out of olMapController.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards,
Martijn Senden

Comment: The error that you show does not suggest that OpenLayers is not loaded yet. It suggests that whatever code tries to use `olMapController` tries to use it before it is defined. Some code in `'directives/olMap'` maybe?

Comment: The controller in the sample code I gave only requires OpenLayers. In my real app, it requires more. When I remove the OpenLayers dependency from it, the error goes away. That's why I think OpenLayers is not yet loaded. olMap directive doen't do overly much. It creates a new OpenLayers map using a class defined in the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry this answer will only contain text as your code is too big for a small example.

I would suggest to write a directive that utilizes [head.js](http://headjs.com) to load libraries you need at a specific context. One could also think of a directive that initializes `openLayers` this way.

I guess your error is a timing problem, because the `require.js` and `angular.js` module loading gets out of sync - more precisely there seems to be no sync at all between them.

**update**
To repeat my comment which lastly helped to lead the OP in the right direction:

*You have to decide which framework gives the tone. If you go with requireJS, then require everything and bootstrap angular manually. (Remove ng-app="" from index.html) and do `angular.bootstrap()´ when requirejs has completed. So the problem most likely is, that angular starts too early.*

Comment: A timing problem it sure is. I really want the AMD modules requireJS provides. I think head.js is not going to help me much. I have angular and require working together, it just doesn't work on this controller with the OpenLayers dependency.

Comment: That was the point of the answer. You have to decide which framework gives the tone. If you go with requireJS, then require everything and bootstrap angular manually. (Remove `ng-app=""` from index.html) and do `angular.bootstrap()´ when requirejs has completed. So the problem most likely is, that angular starts too early.

Comment: Good point. I already have a domReady function (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) that waits for the dom to load before Angular is bootstrapped, so I'm not using ng-app. However, it might be the dom is ready, but require is not. How would I check if require is finished loading everything?

Comment: What if I would call the domReady function from the requirejs callback function? (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-callback)

Answer (score 6):

Well, just for reference my final solution. The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410284/using-openlayers-with-requirejs-and-angularjs#comment32312631_21412540) by [angabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143300/angabriel) set me off in the right direction.

[Like i said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410284/using-openlayers-with-requirejs-and-angularjs#comment32321304_21412540), I'm using the [domReady module](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) provided by [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) to bootstrap Angular. This is still being called to early, because OpenLayers isn't loaded yet when angular starts. RequireJS also provides a callback property in require.config. This is a function that is triggered when all the dependencies are loaded. So I used that function to require the angular bootstrap module. My config now looks like this:

```
require.config(
    {
        baseUrl: 'scripts',
        paths: {
            // Vendor modules
            angular: 'vendor/angular/angular',
            domReady: 'vendor/domReady',
            openLayers: 'vendor/openlayers-debug',
            etcetera....

        },
        shim: {
            angular: {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: 'angular'
            },
            openLayers: {
                exports: 'OpenLayers'
            },
        },
        deps: ['angular',
            'openLayers',
            'app',
            'domReady',
            'controllers/rootController',
            'controllers/olMapController',
            'directives/olMap'
        ],
        callback: function() {
            require(['bootstrap']);
        }
    }
);
```

And the bootstrap module looks like this:

```
define(['angular', 'domReady', 'app'], function(angular, domReady) {
    domReady(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['GRVP']);
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help. [@angabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143300/angabriel): I upvoted your comment. It's not possible to accept a comment as an answer, is it? Your initial answer wasn't really the answer to my question, but the comment helped a lot...

Regards, Martijn

Comment: Thank you, great you posted your solution. I added that helpful comment to my answer so you might kindly upvote it ;).