# Angular JS with Open Layers

Tags: angularjs, openlayers

I need to create a controller that has a service which manage all the markers of open layers.

I think that there are apps that based on angular and use also open layers.
However i can't find real examples.

Can someone help me find good examples for this approach?

Comment: I know nothing about angularjs, but a word of warning: markers are deprecated in OpenLayers, use an OpenLayers.Feature.Vector with an externalGraphic instead.

Comment: Did you chekc out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410284/using-openlayers-with-requirejs-and-angularjs

Answer (score 3):

Azimuth project is I think the most most advanced integration of angular and open layers (or leaflet).

But... It's really not that hard to create custom directives that display maps and listen for changes on scope objects in order to draw them on the map. Here is a plukr I created for another SO issue of mine, but it shows you how to create a basic map : http://plnkr.co/edit/0tXsWS0DXtl37jV8GywI?p=preview

```
app.directive('tchOlMap', function () {

    var MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID = 'tchMap';

    return {

        restrict: 'E',

        replace: true,
        template: '<div id="' + MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID + '" class="full-height"></div>',

        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map(MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID);
            map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(3, 47).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")), 5);
        }
    }

});
```

You just have to watch for a scope object in the link function, and draw on the map accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

please check out this https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive

Here we have set of examples use this Marker custom icon example